# Not able to Parse DataTime From String to DATETIME

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datetime

I am trying to Convert Date from string `"01-07-2015"`. I have tried all method `DateTime.Parse` and `DateTime.ParseExact` and cultural Varaint too but I am not able to parse the datetime.

```
string dateTimeString = item.startDate; 
var dateTime = DateTime.Parse(item.startDate); 
DateTime edate = DateTime.Parse(item.endDate);
if (sdate <= datetime && datetime <= edate)
{
    periodList.Add(item.fsid);
}
```

Output I am getting is `{01-01-0001 12:00:00:AM}`

Comment: debug and check what value are you getting for `item.startDate`?

Comment: `DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Parse("01-07-2015");` this works just fine. In your case `DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Parse(item.startDate.ToShortDateString());`

Comment: item.startDate i am getting 01-07-2015

Comment: Try like this `Datetime s = DateTime.Parse("01-07-2015")`? Does it succeed? what value does `s` gets?

Comment: @WaqarAhmed Convert.ToDateTime(item.startDate) it works for me but now i deploy it in azure now i am getting String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: Try with `DateTime.ParseExact("01-07-2015", "d-M-yyyy", new CultureInfo("en-SG"));`

Comment: What about ParseExact?

Comment: @NeerajMehta You told on Convert.ToDateTime(...) work in local but fails with "string not recognized as valid DateTime", so did you try enable logging and see what value was there in your Azure environment? Your local data might come correct but cross check the data on Azure too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
var dateTime = "01-07-2015";
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(dateTime, "mm-dd-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

[demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/EfFZmO).

Comment: Getting same Output  {01-01-0001 12:00:00:AM}

Comment: Yes it works for me . .. thanks just change dd-MM-yyyy